# Не могу зайти в аккаунт Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Возникла такая проблема при входе в аккаунт в visual studio окно для ввода данных просто зависло. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это окно использует браузер. Попробуйте залогиниться вашим IE в свой аккуант на сайте майкрософта

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобрался в чем дело. У меня была старая версия Internet Explorer. Обновил до 11 версии. Так же в нем был по умолчанию отключен JavaScript, нужно обязательно включить. После этого все заработало

Answer (score 0):

У меня наблюдает эта проблема в упрошенном виде 5-20 секунд также тупит не погружаясь.

1. Попробуйте подождать пару минут
2. Попробуйте войти в аккаунт microsoft в основном браузере
3. Попробуйте отключить антивирус и брендмаузер
4. Попробуйте отключить VPN (или иные туннели)

Comment: @sirAllone вы можете оформить это решение ответ